# What is this solar path light component?

Tags: led, solar-cell, charger, light

Just for fun and curiosity, I decided to reverse engineer an old, cheap solar path light. It's a fairly simple circuit, but there's a component I can't find any information on. It has transistor-style package with four leads. The markings are 6608A H13006. A Google search yields nothing. I suspect there's a diode function in there since it connects to the solar panel and the battery. Does anyone know what this component is or does?

Top of solar path lamp circuit board:

[image: Top of solar path lamp circuit board.]

6608A H13006 component:

[image: 6608A H13006 component]

Bottom of the solar path lamp circuit board:

[image: Bottom of the solar path lamp circuit board.]

Comment: Likely a clone of YX8018 1.25V Solar LED Driver chip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is an integrated solar lamp controller and boost converter.

It is probably similar to this YX8018 device that can control the LED to turn on when the sun sets and also boost the 1.2V from the NiMH cell to the voltage needed by the LED.

Note that the only other component on the PCB is a small inductor.

[image]

Image credit : https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/710956/Shiningic/YX8018/1

Answer (score 1):

An all in one nimh solar panel charger and led boost switching regulator circuit. It senses when the solar panel is producing voltage to turn off the led driver part.

Like the YX8018 or countless clones. The YX8018 also being a clone of some TI or AD or whatever us manufacturer part.

See https://ez.analog.com/adieducation/university-program/b/blogs/posts/hacking-an-led-solar-garden-light for a good breakdown of how they work.

Comment: Great link! I would choose this as the equally best answer as well.

Comment: @phil these are neat little class of devices. And as you are new, you know you can upvote multiple answers if they help you. You can only accept one as "the" answer and thats totally up to your decision of which is the best for you. I'm just glad to help.